# Difference between MongoDb and module mongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

What is the difference between the npm module MongoDB and the downloaded MongoDb?

Comment: Downloaded MongoDB is actual SoftWare. Package MongoDB is just a library code that makes operations on SW easy.

Comment: So Tushar,we need both of them ?

Comment: First one(SW) is COMPULSORY, second depends on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "downloaded MongoDB" (from [here](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads)) is the actual database server software (MongoDB itself). The [mongodb npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) is the node.js native client driver used to access the services of a MongoDB database server from a node.js app.